# List Add-ins and Disable them

Tags: excel, vba

I am using two procedures:

A. List active Add-in Names in a sheet (works fine)

```
Sub ListAddins()
Dim lngrow As Long, objAddin As AddIn
Sheet1.Range("AG1:AH1000").ClearContents
lngrow = 1
With Sheet1
For Each objAddin In Application.AddIns
.Cells(lngrow, "AG").Value = objAddin.Name
.Cells(lngrow, "AH").Value = objAddin.FullName
lngrow = lngrow + 1
Next objAddin
End With
End Sub
```

B. Going through the Add-In Names and disabling them

```
Sub disable_addins()
Dim cell As Range, rng2 As Range, addstr As String
Set rng2 = Xloader.Range("AH1:AH" & Xloader.Range("AH65536").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each cell In rng2
addstr = cell.Value
Application.AddIns(addstr).Installed = False
Next cell
End Sub
```

I am getting an error Subscript Out of Range on penultimate line of procedure B. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application.AddIns` property doesn't work with either the `Name` or the `FullName` of the add-in. It *needs* the add-in **`Title`**!

So, for column AH, do this instead of `FullName`:

```
.Cells(lngrow, "AH").Value = objAddin.Title
                                      ^^^^^
```

Then procedure B should work as expected.

Or you could add a new piece of add-in information in column AI like this in procedure A:

```
.Cells(lngrow, "AI").Value = objAddin.Title
```

and reference that column in procedure B, if you want to keep seeing the `FullName` in its own column.